# Is it possible to integrate a polynomial division in an align environment?

Tags: math-mode, align, polynom

MWE:

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage{
            amsmath,
            polynom
           }
\polyset{
         vars = s,
         style = C
        }

\begin{document}

  \begin{align}
                                     Y &= \underbrace{\frac{1 + s}{-24 + 26s - 9s^2 + s^3}}_{G}U.
    \intertext{Ein Pol von $G$ raten:}
                                   p_1 &= 2.
    \intertext{Polynomdivision:}
    %\polylongdiv{s^3-9s^2+26s-24}{s-2}% generates many errors
    \left(s^3-9s^2+26s-24\right):(s-2) &= s^2-7s+12\ldots
  \end{align}
  \[\polylongdiv{s^3-9s^2+26s-24}{s-2}\]

\end{document}
```

Thank you for your help and effort in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could just brace `\polylongdiv{...}{...}` like

```
{\polylongdiv{...}{...}}
```

but the alignment would be off as well. A workaround could be to measure the amount of backing up:

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage{amsmath,mathtools,polynom}

\polyset{
  vars = s,
  style = C
}

\begin{document}

\begin{align}
Y &= \underbrace{\frac{1 + s}{-24 + 26s - 9s^2 + s^3}}_{G}U.
\shortintertext{Ein Pol von $G$ raten:}
p_1 &= 2.
\intertext{Polynomdivision:}
&\settowidth{\dimen0}{%
  $\displaystyle\bigl({}-{}s^3-9s^2+26s-24\bigr)\div\bigl(s-2\bigr)$%
}%
\hspace*{-\dimen0}\!\!{\polylongdiv{s^3-9s^2+26s-24}{s-2}}\\
(s^3-9s^2+26s-24):(s-2) &= s^2-7s+12
\end{align}

\end{document}
```

I used `\shortintertext` for the first one, so the spacing is not so dramatic.

[image]

On the other hand, I can't see why trying to align very disparate things, so I suggest to `gather`:

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage{amsmath,mathtools,polynom}

\polyset{
  vars = s,
  style = C
}

\begin{document}

\begin{equation}
Y = \underbrace{\frac{1 + s}{-24 + 26s - 9s^2 + s^3}}_{G}U.
\end{equation}
Ein Pol von $G$ raten:
\begin{equation}
p_1 = 2.
\end{equation}
Polynomdivision:
\begin{gather}
\begin{gathered} % for centering the equation number
\!\!{\polylongdiv{s^3-9s^2+26s-24}{s-2}}
\end{gathered}\\
(s^3-9s^2+26s-24):(s-2) = s^2-7s+12
\end{gather}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Apparently, `\polylongdiv` adds two thin spaces at the left.

Use `\begin{gathered}[t]` if you want the equation number at the top, rather than centered on the diagram.

Answer (score 2):

They don't nest well. but you could do this

[image]

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage{
            amsmath,
            polynom
           }
\polyset{
         vars = s,
         style = C
        }

\begin{document}

  \begin{align}
                                     Y &= \underbrace{\frac{1 + s}{-24 + 26s - 9s^2 + s^3}}_{G}U.
    \intertext{Ein Pol von $G$ raten:}
                                   p_1 &= 2.
    \intertext{Polynomdivision:}
    &\parbox{.6\textwidth}{\polylongdiv{s^3-9s^2+26s-24}{s-2}}\\
    \left(s^3-9s^2+26s-24\right):(s-2) &= s^2-7s+12\ldots
  \end{align}


\end{document}
```